# Datamapper into String

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I want to be able to see the string like the TwitchTV name I have in my database. Here is my current code

```
get '/watch/:id' do |id|
  erb :mystream
  @result = Twitchtvst.all( :fields => [:Twitchtv ], 
               :conditions => { :user_id => "#{id}" }           
             )  
  puts @result              
end
```

result in terminal;

```
#< Twitchtvst:0x007fb48b4d5a98 >
```

How do I get that into a string (TwitchTV answer in database)

---

Opppppsss!

Here is the real code sample. Sorry!

```
  get '/livestream' do
    erb :livestream
    @users_streams = Twitchtvst.all   
    puts @users_streams
  end
```

If I add .to_s at users_stream it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `.to_csv`, not exactly a string, but it should show the content:

```
get '/livestream' do
    erb :livestream
    @users_streams = Twitchtvst.all   
    @users_streams.each do |us|
        p us.to_csv
    end
  end
```

Comment: that gives me this in terminal #<DataMapper::Collection:0x007f9e10c64318>

Comment: You can also try `.inspect`. Alternatively try to use pry, then you can use your application interactively. After installing that gem add binding.pry after getting @result and inspect it's capabilities. You may have to decide what to convert to an string.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a Collection of Twitchtvst objects, so you need to convert each to a String:

```
puts Twitchtvst.all.map(&:to_s).join
```

Comment: This is the output I get from writing that code; #<Twitchtvst:0x007ff2ead51b20>#<Twitchtvst:0x007ff2ead51850>#<Twitchtvst:0x007ff2ead515d0>#<Twitchtvst:0x007ff2ead51350>