# Datamapper into String/Integer

Tags: ruby, datamapper

```
get '/watch/:id' do |id|
  erb :mystream
  @result = Twitchtvst.all( :fields => [:Twitchtv ], 
               :conditions => { :user_id => "#{id}" }           
             )  
  puts @result              
end
```

result in terminal;

```
#< Twitchtvst:0x007fb48b4d5a98 >
```

How do I get that into a string (TwitchTV answer in database)

Comment: By adding `.to_s`, so that the line reads `puts @result.to_s`, if that method is implemented in class Twitchtvst.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117856/datamapper-into-string